# c# handle single double quote in the string(json)

Tags: c#, json, double-quotes

I'm using c# to handle JSON format to parse some data and I have encountered situation where i get this kind of JSON:

```
"{"imperial":" 54 1/4" "}"
```

As you can see there's an inch symbol(double quote) after

```
1/4
```

that leads me to an error.
how can i handle this double quote?

I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON to parse JSON and I tried many ways such as replacing " to ' which gives me the same error.

I thought about regex maybe? any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Correcting the page that generates the invalid JSON?

Comment: The problem is that this JSON is incorrect. You can do **nothing** elegant and correct about it. Anything you do will be a **hack** but not a solution. Your JSON supplier should have escaped this symbol and teaching him how to JSON is much better than using `replace`, `Regex` or constructing any other workarounds.

Comment: @xanatos no i'm working on windows forms and i'm getting the json from the response and trying to parse

Comment: @General-Doomer yeah i thought about regex but couldn't dig in.... i'll try what you gave me.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev right i wish i can tell him... and the problem is i can't..

Answer (score 2):

Code (for string like `<NUMBER>/<NUMBER><DOUBLE QUOTE>`):

```
string json = "{\"imperial\":\" 54 1/4\" \"}";
string convertedJson = Regex.Replace(json, @"(\d+\/\d+)""", "$1\\\"");

var res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(convertedJson);
```

Result (convertedJson):

```
{"imperial":" 54 1/4\" "}
```

Comment: i think this would work only for `<NUMBER>/<NUMBER><DOUBLE QUOTE>` like you said. can you do a regex with a-zA-Z and any special characters? i have `{"description":"this is a tall product(up to 55")."}"`

Comment: I dont know all variants of your json, you can try `@"(\d+)"""` pattern (format `<NUMBER><DOUBLE QUOTE>`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape at least HTML characters (which include the quotes) before feeding the parser.

If you have control of the generator of the JSON you are receiving and you are using also Newtonsoft, Newtonsoft.JSON's `JsonWriter` class has a property called `StringEscapeHandling`.

This property can hold several values: `Default`, `EscapeNonAscii` and `EscapeHTML` (have a look at the [doc](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm))

In your case, the `EscapeHTML` is the most interesting. Quoting the doc:

> `EscapeHTML`: HTML (<, >, &, ', ") and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.